# ROS Navigation - AMCL not transforming map to odom

Tags: ros, navigation, transform, amcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am running a turtlebot 2 with an RPLidar instead of a Kinect, trying to get the navigation stack working.

I am unable to get AMCL to transform map to odom. My current tf tree looks like this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-2f_ZBhV2PKVkhCZW1vaVY3em8/view?usp=sharing

I am running two transform scripts between base_link and base_footprint, and base_link and base_laser. When I execute move_base.launch, I get the following error: `[ WARN] [1500318096.546547244]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.100719 timeout was 0.1.`

In my launch file, I have: `<include file="$(find tb2_2dnav)/launch/amcl.launch.xml" />` which references:

```
<launch>
  <arg name="scan_topic"     default="scan"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_x" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_y" default="0.0"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_a" default="0.0"/>

  <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl">

    <param name="min_particles"             value="500"/>
    <param name="max_particles"             value="3000"/>
    <param name="kld_err"                   value="0.02"/>
    <param name="update_min_d"              value="0.20"/>
    <param name="update_min_a"              value="0.20"/>
    <param name="resample_interval"         value="1"/>
    <param name="transform_tolerance"       value="0.5"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_slow"       value="0.00"/>
    <param name="recovery_alpha_fast"       value="0.00"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_x"            value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_y"            value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
    <param name="initial_pose_a"            value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
    <param name="gui_publish_rate"          value="50.0"/>

    <remap from="scan"                      to="$(arg scan_topic)"/>
    <param name="laser_max_range"           value="3.5"/>
    <param name="laser_max_beams"           value="180"/>
    <param name="laser_z_hit"               value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_z_short"             value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_max"               value="0.05"/>
    <param name="laser_z_rand"              value="0.5"/>
    <param name="laser_sigma_hit"           value="0.2"/>
    <param name="laser_lambda_short"        value="0.1"/>
    <param name="laser_likelihood_max_dist" value="2.0"/>
    <param name="laser_model_type"          value="likelihood_field"/>

    <param name="odom_model_type"           value="diff"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha1"               value="0.1"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha2"               value="0.1"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha3"               value="0.1"/>
    <param name="odom_alpha4"               value="0.1"/>
    <param name="odom_frame_id"             value="odom"/>
    <param name="base_frame_id"             value="base_footprint"/>

  </node>
</launch>
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and why AMCL is not transforming map to odom.

Edit:

This morning I noticed that I also get this message: `[ WARN] [1500393926.336248116]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 1500393926.336100 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.` I verified that the `/scan` topic was being published to and that the base_scanner was connected in my tf tree.

I also received this warning: `[ WARN] [1500394267.315925339]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.amcandl.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.` so I did as said and got: 
`[DEBUG] [1500393934.597976349]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Removed oldest message because buffer is full, count` 
`[DEBUG] [1500393933.564483123]: MessageFilter [target=odom ]: Added message in frame laser at time 1500393933.356, count now 100`

`rostopic info /scan`: https://www.pastiebin.com/596e3ca4ac1db 
`rosnode info /amcl`: https://www.pastiebin.com/596e3b8b37865

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/266598/ros-navigation---amcl-not-transforming-map-to-odom/) by [xnick77x](https://answers.ros.org/users/30994/xnick77x/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2017-07-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

add a flag to check what is going on with amcl, like this:

`<node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">`

also, are you sure your laser scan is published in the `/scan` topic?

---

Originally posted by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) with karma: 4402 on 2017-07-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [xnick77x](https://answers.ros.org/users/30994/xnick77x/) on 2017-07-18**:
I added the screen output and didn't see any change. Instead I tried the debug logger as my edit to my question says. I also did verify that /scan was being published to.

**Comment by [Procópio](https://answers.ros.org/users/1112/proc%C3%B3pio/) on 2017-07-18**:
please paste the output of:   `rostopic info /scan` and `rosnode info /amcl`

**Comment by [xnick77x](https://answers.ros.org/users/30994/xnick77x/) on 2017-07-18**:
Appended to my question. Thanks. I did notice that in `rostopic echo /scan` the frame_id is `laser` but in the tf_tree, it's `base_laser`. Is that an issue?

**Comment by [Humpelstilzchen](https://answers.ros.org/users/21851/humpelstilzchen/) on 2017-07-18**:
Of course this is an issue. A frame_id that is part of your tf-tree is needed to find the origin of your sensor input.

**Comment by [xnick77x](https://answers.ros.org/users/30994/xnick77x/) on 2017-07-18**:
I changed the frame_id in the params in the launch file to match base_laser, but that hasn't fixed any of my errors/warnings.

**Comment by [xnick77x](https://answers.ros.org/users/30994/xnick77x/) on 2017-07-18**:
I restarted everything and it worked. I guess the issue was the frame_id. Thanks for the help